# Applying SMOTE on time series data

Tags: time-series, class-imbalance, smote

I have a dataset that consist of student grades and it's based on a time series. I used LSTM to predict the student future grade. Can I apply SMOTE on this dataset to ensure that the model will not be biased towards certain student grades?

Comment: Why shouldn’t it be biased toward certain grades?

Comment: At least with LSTM models on text problems I didn’t think it made sense to synthesize data with SMOTE because the generated vectors would represent an unnatural sequence of grammatically incorrect & non-existent word sequences. I suspect similar goes for time series?

Comment: @Dave Without applying SMOTE on the dataset, the final prediction might not be accurate right? for example, the model prediction maybe good towards students who scored A, while not so good for those students who scored D

Comment: I would argue the exact opposite, that altering the class ratio results in bogus predictions. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Comment: @eliangius The data is already preprocessed from strings to integer, so that shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: @Mack Still a prob even with text converted to integer indices of the vocab, SMOTE would likely find artificial fractional values between these indices that cannot be interpreted as words..

Comment: @Dave Thanks for sharing the links. Why researchers still uses SMOTE whenever they deal with an imbalanced dataset?

Comment: @Mack How dubious practices arose interests me, but it is hard to say. In that first link, Sycorax gives a possibility that seems plausible.