# Steps for balancing data using SMOTE

Tags: machine-learning, classification, class-imbalance

Right now I'm doing sentiment analysis (classification) with TF-IDF and SVM linear. My data is not balanced and I want to make data balance using SMOTE from `imbalanced-learn`. The problem is SMOTE can't convert string to float so steps what I do right now is:

1. Imbalance data.
2. Split data into data train and test.
3. Apply TF-IDF.
4. Use SMOTE.

I want to ask. If I change my steps like this:

1. Imbalance data.
2. Apply TF-IDF.
3. Apply SMOTE.
4. Split data into data train and test.

Is it okay?

Comment: Why do you want to balance the class ratio? Depending on the circumstances, [I would argue that doing so leads to bogus predictions.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/106205/73930)

Comment: I want to predict a sentence, is it a negative or positive sentiment. My data right now have 5000 positive and 1000 negative thats why I need balancing my data.

Comment: Why do you need balanced data to make that prediction?

Comment: So it doesn't need to be balanced for prediction? I'm confused right now.

Comment: What does balancing give you? // In the link I gave, there is a comment of mine with six links. The first one, which is a Stephan Kolassa post on Cross Validated Stack Exchange, and the two blog posts by Frank Harrell will clarify the situation.